# Use onChildClickListener with ExpendableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How do you use onClickListener with Expendable List view in such a way that clicking a child item creates a new Activity?

I already did what this guy [made](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/) but don't have ANY idea how to make the child item create a new Activity. He explained the bit in the comments but don't know what to go after

```
 ExpandListChild ch =  ExpListItems.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition);
```

I also included

```
ExpandList.setOnChildClickListener(ExpandList_ItemClicked);
```

on the onCreate method. I know I have to do something about the 'ch' variable, but don't know what its values corresponding to the clicked item are. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onChildClick (ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
```

When your ChildClick listener is called you get all the information you need, so ch is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, man. I figured it out, but you confirmed what I'm doing is right. Looks like ch is redundant. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 ExpandList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, int arg3, long arg4) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Try this.